# Joining same table multiple times is throwing error

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql code

```
SELECT * FROM `user_credentials` 
  JOIN `friends` ON `friends`.`1stpal` = `user_credentials`.`cred_regiden`  
  JOIN `friends` ON `friends`.`2ndpal` = `user_credentials`.`cred_regiden` 
WHERE (`cred_fname` LIKE'".$search_text. "%') AND (`friends`.`1stpal` = '$current_user'
  OR `friends`.`2ndpal` = '$current_user')  LIMIT 0, 5;
```

I'm trying to join the table 'friends' two times and this throws error: Not unique table/alias: 'friends'. When I change the script to following,

```
SELECT * FROM `user_credentials` 
  JOIN `friends` AS `f1` ON `friends`.`1stpal` = `user_credentials`.`cred_regiden`  
  JOIN `friends` AS `f2` ON `friends`.`2ndpal` = `user_credentials`.`cred_regiden` 
WHERE (`cred_fname` LIKE'".$search_text. "%') AND (`friends`.`1stpal` = '$current_user'
  OR `friends`.`2ndpal` = '$current_user')  LIMIT 0, 5;
```

It now says: `Unknown column 'friends.1stpal'`. 
When I run the single join, it works perfectly. But that is not I want, I want results from both the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use table aliases (abbreviations) when joining to the same table more than once.  They need to be used throughout the query to disambiguate the columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user_credentials` uc JOIN
     `friends` `f1`
     ON f1.`1stpal` = uc.`cred_regiden` JOIN
     `friends` `f2`
     ON f2.`2ndpal` = uc.`cred_regiden` 
WHERE (uc.`cred_fname` LIKE'".$search_text. "%') AND
      '$current_user' in (f1.`2ndpal`, f2.`1stpal`)
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Note:  I am guessing as to the second condition in the `where` clause.  It could be:

```
 '$current_user' in (f2.`2ndpal`, f1.1stpal`)
```

Some more comments:

- If you use table aliases, you might as well use them for all tables for readability.
- Don't use backticks around column names that don't need them.  They just clutter the query.
- Using `limit` without an `order by` could be dangerous.  The rows returned will match but could change from query to query.
- `in` is easier to write and understand than long sequences of `or` expressions (or even short sequences).

Answer (score 0):

On the second example you still use table friends but you should use either f1 or f2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you named it the tables with alias f1 and f2, you should use them in the query:

```
... ON `f1`.`1stpal` ...
```